# how to make nginx find static html from specific folder

Tags: php, nginx

I want to make nginx to look up for a specific folder to get the static html, if it doesn't found it ,it will try php file to dynamically generate the content, I tried this:

```
location /mysite {
  try_files /mysite/path/to/static/html?$uri /mysite/path/to/php/index.php
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 2m;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

but I got 403 forbidden error, it seems like nginx only search this folder `/path/to/static/html?$uri` and if not find it, will not search `/path/to/php/index.php`

Why this happen? How to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code? there's a missing semi colon on the `try_files` line, fix it and restart nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `try_files` block isn’t quite correct and that’s the reason why it’s not working. The comment @Mohammad AbuShady left on your question is true as well, you need a semicolon at the end of the line. But your nginx shouldn’t even start with this wrong syntax so I guess this was just some typo in your question.

```
try_files /some/path$uri /some/path/index.php;
```

That’s it, simply leave out that question mark, because the question mark at this point is a literal and included in the path as is (no regular expression).